# MVC 5 - Is it possible to reuse Custom MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider, asp.net-identity, custom-membershipprovider

I am migrating an existing application from web forms to MVC 5, and I am looking to re-use our custom membership provider(implementing System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider interface). Jumping to ASP.Net Identity is something we would consider down the line - it doesn't seem to work well with the database first model.

Any thoughts/advice welcome!
Keith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the CustomMembership sample at https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/CustomMembershipSample/ Hope you find that helpful